# Правильные именования (naming convention)

Tags: java

Добрый день всем. Всех с первым апреля. )

Мне как .net разработчику приятней писать интерфейс IDemoView - имплементацию DemoView,
но часто, как вижу, в проектах делают так: интерфейс DemoView - имплементацию DemoViewImpl. Как делать правильней? Просто первый проект делаю на Java.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java принят вариант с DemoView - DemoViewImpl, хотя, вообще, имя реализации должно отражать чуть больше, нежели просто то, что, мол, смотри, друг, я — реализация!

Посмотрите на стандартную библиотеку коллекций, (Set -> HashSet, TreeSet) название реализации несёт информацию о том, на какой основе (технологии, способе) этот интерфейс реализован.

Comment: спасибо. хорошо а почему тут человек все таки пришел к IMailView http://habrahabr.ru/post/113121/

Comment: Спросите у этого человека, почему он решил сделать именно так. Вам никто не запрещает так именовать свои интерфейсы, но видели ли вы хотя бы одно подобное именование в стандартной библиотеке?

Comment: нет, я ясно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

-Impl это тоже очень плохо. Допускается если интерфейс имеет единственную реализацию. Стандартное соглашение: View -> DemoView. Оно же должно использоваться в 99.9% случаев.